# Remove row from CSV file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Is there a way to remove a row from a CSV file without rewriting then entire thing?

Currently, I am using a dictionary 'db' that contains the database with the row I want to delete, first I read the columns, then a completely rewrite every row in the CSV besides for the row with the ID I want to delete, is there a way to do this without having to rewrite everything?

```
 def remove_from_csv(file_name, id, db):
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            i = next(reader)

        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerow(i)
            for i in db:
                if id != i:
                    for j in db[i]:
                        writer.writerow([i, j, db[i][j]])
```

Comment: if you want to only use a single file then you have to read the whole thing into memory and then write it back out, there no way around that. how do you know which rows to delete? do you have a number? a string match? if its something simple you can just look line by line, something a bit more advanced and you can use the `csv` module and if its real fancy then use `pandas`

Comment: @NoeHorowitz what you're doing is actually the proper way (on the principle at least - writing to a new file then renaming -, can't comment on your exact code since it's not a proper [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way I have done so in the past is to use a `pandas` dataframe and the `drop` function based on the row index or label.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourFile.csv')
```

```
newDf = df.drop('rowLabel')
```

or by index position:

```
newDf =df.drop(df.index[indexNumber])
```